# Call own function from loaded script in frida cli - Output "undefinied"

Tags: javascript, android, frida

I need an expert for the frida cli.

In my current situation i loaded frida with:

```
frida -U -p XXX -l test.js --no-pause
```

In this script there is the following code:

```
function test(parameter) { console.log(parameter); }
```

Everytime when i call in the frida cli the function, the parameter is logged correctly.

Frida adds "undefined".

**Output:**

```
<parameter's value>
undefined
```

Anybody knows why frida outputs undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Because the javascript evalution of the script you loaded doesn't return anything.

`function test(param) { console.log(param); return 1; }`

will print the param and "1" instead of undefined.

If you want to disable this behavior just edit `frida_tools/repl.py#_eval_and_print`

```
    if output != 'undefined':  # add this condition
        self._print(output)
    return success
```

[source code](https://github.com/frida/frida-tools/blob/master/frida_tools/repl.py#L256)